# Get POCO object from IDataReader using Dapper

Tags: dapper

I want Dapper to give me an object for the current row of an `IDataReader`. That is:

```
T Map<T>(IDataReader reader) => ?
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think that is possible with the core library. is there a specific reason you want DataReader object ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Dapper can do it:

```
IEnumerable<YourPoco> result = Dapper.SqlMapper.Parse<YourPoco>(yourIDatareader);
```

Comment: That gives me `IEnumerable<YourPoco>` for the whole reader. I need `YourPoco` for the current row.

Comment: Use `IDataReader.GetRowParser` extension, see the readme.txt here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md -

Comment: @MaurGi  Thank you. This was very helpful. Good old Dapper. Never fails to impress.

Answer (score 1):

The [comment by MaurGi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545191/2540235) to use the [IDataReader.GetRowParser extension](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md#type-switching-per-row) led me to the **Answer for Visual Basic with Dapper:**

```
Dim parser = Dapper.SqlMapper.GetRowParser(Of YourPoco)(reader)

Dim entity = parser(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Current row I'm not sure about but what you can do is use DynamicMap to Map the entire datareader data and pick what you want from there

```
var myObjects = Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<MyClass>>(dataReader);
```